# Getting children of field container in EXT JS 4

Tags: extjs4

I have a simple question, even though it has been given me quite a headache.

I have a field container which have some radio fields added to it:

```
xtype      : 'fieldcontainer',
                            fieldLabel : 'Field type',
                            defaultType: 'radiofield',
                            defaults: {
                                flex: 1
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    boxLabel  : 'Plain Text',
                                    name      : 'plain-text',
                                    inputValue: 'plain-text',
                                    id        : 'plain-text'
                                }, {
                                    boxLabel  : 'Rich Text',
                                    name      : 'html-text',
                                    inputValue: 'html-text',
                                    id        : 'html-text'
                                }, {
                                    boxLabel  : 'Time',
                                    name      : 'time',
                                    inputValue: 'time',
                                    id        : 'time'
                                },
                                {
                                    boxLabel  : 'Typed reference',
                                    name      : 'typed-reference',
                                    inputValue: 'typed-reference',
                                    id        : 'typed-reference'
                                },
                                {
                                    boxLabel  : 'Date',
                                    name      : 'date',
                                    inputValue: 'date',
                                    id        : 'date'
                                }

                            ],

                            listeners: {
                                added: function(radiofield) {
                                    ??

                                }
```

I tried almost everything inspecting the radiofield object, like iterating its items.items array for added items, however, I only get the integer value of the item, not the object itself. I want to iterate alle items added to the container to set a checked value on a radio field that meets a specific criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`query([selector])`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-query)

> Retrieves all descendant components which match the passed selector.
>   Executes an Ext.ComponentQuery.query using this container as its root.

Comment: I like CD's answer because it was fast to implement. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't use RadionGroup? Anyway; Items are of type Ext.util.MixedColletion which provide you with the each method http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.AbstractMixedCollection-method-each

Try the following

```
// define a function within the scope of the fieldcontainer(instance)
handlerFunction: functio(item) {
    // item is the instance of your radiofield
    // you can access any property or call any method
    if (item.name === 'html-text') {
         item.setValue('html-text');
    }
}

fieldcontainerInstance.items.each(handlerFunction,handlerFunctionScope);
```

Comment: You're right, I've changed it to RadioGroup - makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type item.query() to get all items it has.